# how to pin an rpm package to the current kernel ?

Tags: kernel-module, rpmbuild

i need to build an rpm which include a kernel module ( the module will be added to directory /lib/modules/%current_kernel/extra/)
the problem i am having is that if  the linux machine where my package will be installed  the kernel is updated afterward , the module doesn't get transferred on the new kernel  /lib/modules/*%new_kernel*/extra/
so i was wondering whether there was a way of building the rpm with dependencies on the current kernel , so that my package is either uninstalled during the kernel upgrade or re-installed 
thanks 
Luc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can look into [kmods](https://rpmfusion.org/Packaging/KernelModules/Kmods2). Unfortunately, Fedora is officially [a bunch of jerks concerning kernel modules](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Packaging:Guidelines#No_External_Kernel_Modules), so the official recommendation is currently "you can't." (**Edit**: 19 Dec 2019 - the Packaging Guidelines [moved](https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/packaging-guidelines/) and now make no reference to kernel modules at all.)

Another solution that I use is to have a fake startup service that attempts to rebuild and load the driver on every boot. This required the end user to have `kernel-devel` installed, and you have to manually check the version of that package too because otherwise they can upgrade just the kernel but still satisfy your dependencies because an old `kernel-devel` is still installed (just bit me last week).

Comment: @Till I noted it was dead Dec '19.